# How to deserialize a string representation of a list of maps in Dart

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I have a representation of a movie I store in an SQLite database. It consists of an id and a list of genres.

A genre consists of an id and a name.

I'm having trouble deserializing the list of genres after having to flatten the hierarchy to store it as a string in the database.

The list of genres looks like the following in the database:

```
[{id: 1, name: Comedy}, {id: 2, name: Drama}]
```

How do I deserialize the database row into an object of my Movie class?

```
class Genre {
  int id;
  String name;
  Genre({this.id, this.name});
  factory Genre.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => Genre(
        id: map["id"],
        name: map["name"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
      };
}

class Movie {
  int id;
  List<Genre> genres;
  Movie({this.id, this.genres});

  factory SqLiteMovie.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => SqLiteMovie(
        id: map["id"],
        genres: List<Genre>.from(map["genres"].map((x) => Genre.fromMap(x))), // offending line
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "genres": List<dynamic>.from(genres.map((x) => x.toMap())).toString(), // need toString to store in db
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using sqflite plugin, as [documentation](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md) says:

> Nested content is not supported

So you have two options:

- flatten the hierarchy
- encode nested maps and lists as json (or other format), declaring the column as a String.

You can also check this [example](https://steemit.com/programming/@tstieff/using-sqflite-in-your-flutter-applicaiton-effectively)

hope it helps